# Accessing EC2 in case of stuck instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection-timeout

I have my website running on a t2.2xlarge instance (no ELB in between). I am able to SSH to this instance 99% of the time using the key mechanism.

However, when the website is down, sometimes I am not able to SSH to this instance as all though instance state is RUNNING. Timeout error is returned in those 1% cases.

There is no change between the ways when I am able to connect to the instance and when I am not.

Connection method "EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection)" mentioned on AWS EC2 home page also never helped:

[image]

Gone through all the posts and below link but no luck since SSH worked 99% of the time:

[Troubleshooting Connecting to Your Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout)

Best part is "System Status Checks" mentioned on the EC2 home page also show - System reachability check passed. This time I submitted feedback to them regarding this issue but yet to get revert.

I typically wait for few minutes and then restart the instance. This is the worst option but I could not find any alternative.

Please suggest how to find root cause and fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard one.

If, when the problem occurs, it can only be recovered by a reboot, then it makes it hard to debug because you cannot login while the problem is occurring. This type of problem is normally caused by software running on the instance, rather than anything to do with Amazon EC2 itself.

First thing to check would be **Amazon CloudWatch Logs** to see whether the CPU is 100% when the problem happens.

Next thing to check is the **log files on the computer**, which you can examine after the restart. You could configure a script to continually log the CPU and processes in use to a log file, so that you can examine them later to determine the underlying cause.

See:

- [How to log CPU load?](https://askubuntu.com/a/22033)
- [How do I Find Out Linux CPU Utilization? - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Close open SSH connections and allow only specific IP ranges!.

To recover your instance you can trigger a cloudwatch event with reference to this link [Instance recovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html)